# Jetpack Compose Deeplink navigation from Oauth

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm trying to get the `code` from GitHub Oauth API `playground://gh?code=XYZ` in the ViewModel through `savedStateHandler`. My composable screen configuration:

```
NavGraphBuilder.composable(
         route = "login",
         deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink {
            uriPattern = "playground://gh?code={code}"
         })
      ) {
         Log.d("MyLog", it.arguments?.getString("code", "nothing") ?: "null")
         //...
      }
```

`MyLog` is always `nothing`

I also tried to implement the `NavGraphBuilder.composable.arguments` parameter, but the result was the same.

I'm just getting familiar with Compose and went through the Google Code labs. https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#4 - this worked as expected, but the issue is the argument is required.

I also have a WebViewScreen composable that needs a URL and that works.

```
builder.composable(
         route = "browser",
         arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("url") {
               type = NavType.StringType
            }
         ),
         deepLinks = listOf(
            navDeepLink {
               uriPattern = "playground://gh/browser/{url}"
            }
         )
      ) {
         //...
      }
```

Not sure if this can be achieved with Jetpack Compose Navigation or do I have to use the `Intent` approach a pass it to the `ViewModel`?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `arguments` in your first code snippet if you want to parse the `code` argument?

Comment: I tried: _I also tried to implement the NavGraphBuilder.composable.attributes parameter, but the result was the same._

Comment: And by `attributes`, you actually meant...`arguments`?

Comment: Oh, yes, mea culpa. Fixed the description. Thx

Comment: Also tried to put it as a part of the route `login/{code}`, but then just got `"{code}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm in the same situation as you, getting familiar with Jetpack Compose and building an app that uses OAuth authentication.

I've managed to get the authorisation code from the deeplink uri after going through the same codelab that you mentioned.

Try adding this code to your MainActivity to ensure that your callback uri contains the auth code:

```kotlin
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val data: Uri? = intent?.data
        val code = data?.getQueryParameter("code")
        Log.d("MainActivity", "oauth code - $code")
    }
```

It works for me and I can see the code in the log when the authentication is redirected to my app.

I'm using a different method though, I'm using an Implicit Intent to redirect the user to an endpoint for authentication and I'm not using the Github API.

EDIT:

Here is the *composable* parameters:

```kotlin
    composable(
        route = "OAuthRedirectWithCode",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("code") { type = NavType.StringType }),
        deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink { uriPattern = "$uri?code={code}" })
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        val code = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("code")
        Log.d("NavHost", "oauth code - $code")
      }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi. Yes, I'm using the implicit intent as well to open the GitHub login page. After login, the deep link opens my app but the code is empty/null.

Comment: I can see the code in the `onResume`. Would you mind sharing the `NavBuilder` composable parameters, please?

Comment: I got it. I need to copy the exact URI that comes back to the `uriPattern`. I thought I could just read everything.